# Convert R Data Frame to a table

Tags: r, pivot, xtabs

I have a dataframe in R:
[image]

I am trying to convert this into table with restaurant and Overall as columns and sex as a row with Freq filled in as values:
[image]

I have created the intial dataframe using xtabs:
`res<- xtabs(stars~restaurant+sex,aggregate(stars~restaurant+sex,data1,mean))`

and then used dcast to transpose sex column:
`dcast(df, restaurant+Overall ~ sex)`
[image]

But as you can see the values under male and female are populated with overall column and not freq. How do I add the values to be filled with freq column?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- c("burger King", "burger King","KFC", "KFC", "McDonald", "McDonald", "Taco Bell", "Taco Bell")
y <- c("Female", "male", "Female", "male","Female", "male","Female", "male")
z <- runif(8)
t <- c("1.1", "1.1", "1.2", "1.2", "1.3", "1.3", "1.4", "1.4")


df <- tibble(restuarant = x, sex = y, freq = z, overall = t)

#desired output
df %>% group_by(restuarant, overall) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = sex, values_from = freq)
```

Comment: Let me get a sample data and give you a simple workflow